# OWIN Katana Pipeline Earliest Request Bytes Read?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers, owin, katana

With Katana-on-OWIN, what is the earliest point in time I could read the request bytes from a remote client? I want to get at the request headers and content ASAP.

My sample code looks like this:

```
app.Use( async ( env , next ) =>
            {
                foreach ( KeyValuePair<string , object> kvp in env.Environment )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( string.Concat( "Key: " , kvp.Key , ", value: " , kvp.Value ) );
                }
                await next();
            } );
```

So "env" is getting populated by the framework automatically. The HTTP request comes in as bytes (I think?) to the OWIN stack, so I would like to get that byte[] (char[]?) and parse it myself before I have to deal with a lot of Strings. I am looking for certain sets of bytes and don't need the rest of the request.

Thanks.

Comment: This is your earliest opportunity to access the request in Katana. If you really just want to look at raw request bytes then you need to use Sockets directly, no server is going to expose them.